# Anyone had problems with Long Text Fields in Lightning Components on a community not being passed to the server (via apex controller)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

Since Winter 19 went live, we've been having issues with a lightning community and custom lightning components not passing data properly from the component to the apex controller.

This was happening for almost a week since the 14th October on EU1.

We have a lightning:textarea bound to a Long Text Area (32768) field on a custom object, which has a required attribute set dynamically based on certain criteria. Here is a reduced version of the syntax being used.

```
<aura:attribute name="dcn" type="Daily_Care_Note__c" 
                access="private" description="New Daily Care Note"/>
<aura:attribute name="tookBreak" type="Boolean" access="private" description="Were they able to take the break?" default="{!false}"/>
<aura:attribute name="isEvent" type="Boolean" access="private" default="{!false}" description="Is this an event?"/>
<aura:attribute name="isBreak" type="Boolean" access="private" default="{!false}" description="Is this a break?"/>
...
<lightning:textarea aura:id="commentField" name="noteComment"
                    label="Comment" value="{!v.dcn.Comment__c}"
                    required="{!or(and(v.tookBreak, v.isBreak),v.isEvent)}"
/>
```

There are is a toggle set by the user to change v.tookBreak, and v.isBreak/v.isEvent is set based on other inputs.

There is validation in the component helper to check that if the field is required that there is data within it...

```
var comFld = component.find('commentField');
if ($A.util.isEmpty(comFld.get('v.value')) && comFld.get('v.required')) {
  comFld.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
  hasError = true;
}
```

This component has been working perfectly for over a year in it's current form, but as soon as Winter 19 was applied to the org, it has been causing the Comment__c field to not be passed to the server.

There are a number of strange instances where this has been a problem, as it appears that the problem is being seen by many different users, but only within time windows, so there will be no issues whatsoever, then suddenly there'll be a period of time where notes will get created without this Comment__c field being sent to the server from the component.

e.g. between 14/10/18 13:53 to 15:27, we have 62 records without the Comment__c field, out of >4000 created that day.

This happens a few times over the week, the worst was Friday 19th until 15:56 (UK time) when it was then working again. In that time, nearly 200 were missed, again out of >4000 created.

It is as though the components aren't passing the Long Text data or the components aren't respecting the required attributes.

It's just very strange that it affects everyone for a period of time and then works fine, which would indicate a server side problem since we're not making changes to these components when the issue is occurring.

Has anyone else experienced this since Winter 19 went live?

Comment: Could be possibly similar to [this issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000031CYQAY&title=required-rich-text-fields-are-not-indicated-with-symbol), you may like to reach out to the support.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've logged a case already, so I'll see what they come back with and mention this known issue when they do so.